# MySQL + JDBC updateBlob and updateBinaryStream throws NotUpdateable

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I've been searching both Google and StackOverflow for the better part of two hours, and I've not found a solution to this question. So I've turned to asking the question.

I'm working on a project that requires insertion of data into a table. I'm required to use the methods inside the *ResultSet* class (such as *updateXXXXX* and *insertRow*).

Particularly, I need to be able to insert a binary stream/blob (either works in my case). However, the MySQL Java Driver implementation doesn't support this ([implementation here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/JDBC4UpdatableResultSet.java#L67)). In fact, it doesn't support any of the *updateBlob* or *updateBinaryStream* methods.. they throw *NotUpdateable*.

Before you post that I need to create the *Statement* in a way that supports *ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATEABLE*, be assured that I've done that and checked it more than enough times. Please see below:

```
// Create statement that is insensitive to insertion of data, and allows updating.
Statement s = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

// Get an empty query ready for insertion of data
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE 1=0");

// This is a stream of bytes. If it were a String I would be fine.
rs.updateBinaryStream("password", new ByteArrayInputStream(db.password), db.password.length);
```

So the crux of the matter is that from what I can see there's no equivalent way of doing this, without using a different Driver.

If you know of a way of getting this to work, I would absolutely love to hear it. Even if it's just a theory. The last thing I want to do is create multiple columns and store the array as BIGINT compositions of the bytes.

Thanks in advance,
Nick.

Comment: You are *required* to use `insertRow()`? Really? Why?

Comment: @Andreas Cross-compatibility for unknown database softwares.

Comment: And how is an `INSERT` statement less cross-compatible than an updatable `ResultSet` using a dummy `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Fair point. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use updatable result set, especially now that you've concluded that it won't work.

Since you're *"working on a project that requires **insertion** of data into a table"*, you should try using an actual **`INSERT`** statement instead.

Also, you might as well use a `byte[]` method, since that's what you have, instead of trying to use an `InputStream` method.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO TableName (password) VALUES (?)";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setBytes(1, db.password);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: I'll try this out. Thanks.